# What is the field_map_name in findFieldMapIndex ()?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, field-mapping

I am using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro and FieldMappings.

FieldMappings are fiddly and I'm struggling to understand a specific function.

I need to replace an 'old' fieldMap with a 'new' fieldMap. FieldMaps have one or more input fields, and one output field (as I understand it). Because there are more than 1 field in a map, one has to refer to the map by Index. So, we have a handy function to find it: `findFieldMapIndex (field_map_name)`

```
# https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/fieldmappings.htm
# Find a field map within the field mappings by name
findFieldMapIndex (field_map_name)
```

Which is great, but what exactly is the `field_map_name` ?

```
for fldMap in fieldMaps:
    print (fldMap.name)

AttributeError: 'FieldMap' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the field map name, you must use the `getInputFieldName()` function [documentation](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/FieldMap/018z0000007p000000/).

If you are merging input fields, you can have multiple names, so if you are sure you only have one name in your field mapping, you must retrieve it with `getInputFieldName(0)`, where 0 indicates the first field name.

Comment: So essentially then, the name of the entire  field map object is the input field name?